# Eloquent eager loading do not joins?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I remember the old days "discovering" it in a query using the Eloquent, if I used the `with` Laravel do an`inner join`.

Today by chance I checked the queries of a project and ...

```
[2014-11-20 23:21:16] sql.INFO: select * from `ocurrences` where `ocurrences`.`deleted_at` is null order by RAND() limit 4 {"bindings":[],"time":3.58,"name":"mysql"} []
[2014-11-20 23:21:16] sql.INFO: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in ('7') {"bindings":["7"],"time":0.49,"name":"mysql"} []
[2014-11-20 23:21:16] sql.INFO: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '7' limit 1 {"bindings":["7"],"time":0.51,"name":"mysql"} []
[2014-11-20 23:21:16] sql.INFO: select * from `tags` limit 5 {"bindings":[],"time":0.41,"name":"mysql"} []
```

In this case, I'm doing a query like this:

```
/**
 * Get random ocurrences for home
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function randomForHome()
{
  return static::with('user')
    ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
    ->limit(4)
    ->get();
}
```

What is wrong and/or how do I **do joins with Eloquent**?

Comment: L4+ do not joins the tables, I suppose it never did in fact.

Comment: I don't know Jarek. I just remember when I found a solution and this solution is not using `join()`. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in a Laracasts video (thanks Jeffrey!).

I need to use `join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ocurrences.user_id')`. It's a bit logical but I thought with do joins too.

Anyway, here's the final solution:

```
/**
 * Get random ocurrences for home
 * @return Eloquent
 */
public static function randomForHome()
{
  return static::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ocurrences.user_id')
    ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
    ->limit(4)
    ->get();
}
```

Thanks guys.